# Core-plot: How can I set a starting value for the x axis?

Tags: core-plot

I have a core-plot graph, that has values from 50 to 250 and the interval is set to 20. However the labels underneath the graph are as follows: 40, 60, 80, ..., 260. What I want from them is to become: 50, 70, 90, ..., 250. I guess that has to do with the starting value of the x-axis (which is 0 and because the interval is set to 20, the labels are in that condition). I'll be extremely grateful if you suggest a solution for this.

Best regards,
Boyan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `labelingOrigin` to adjust the starting point for fixed interval ticks. Setting it to 10 (or 30 or 50, etc.) will work.